# EntityManagerFactory for every function?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Should i create and close EntityManagerFactory in every function?
or should i create it when the application is starting and close when the application is closed? How can i achieve that?

For example:

I have two functions:

Function that gets objects from database:

```
private List<SomeItems> getItems() {

    List<SomeItems> resultList = new ArrayList<SomeItems>();

    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDatabase");
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    TypedQuery<SomeItems> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "select n from SomeItems n", SomeItems.class);

    resultList = query.getResultList();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();

    return resultList;
}
```

Function that gets only items name:

```
private List<String> getItemsName() {
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDatabase");
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select n.name from SomeItems n", String.class);

resultList = query.getResultList();

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();

return resultList;
}
```

How should i improve that?

Comment: I would expect ALL JPA docs for every JPA provider to mention that an EMF is expensive to create, whilst an EM is cheap. If your provider's docs don't say that then suggest you raise an issue on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not ok to create EntityManagerFactory every time. It is very expensive. Create it once on demand. It is ok for the EntityManager to be created multiple times. But the Factory totally no. You can use a singleton with lazy or eager type of initialization. Your call. Or just a static initializer block somewhere. Many options. The key point is not create the factory on each call reuse instead.   Ok here is one example implementation might not be the best one but it works.

```
 class EntityManagerFactoryHolder {
private static EnityManager entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDatabase");

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManager(){
    return entityManagerFactory;
} 
}
```

This is singleton with EAGER initialization. If you want LAZY look it up in internet.

Comment: Can you give some code sample? and what about closing it later? how can i achieve that?

Comment: well in regards of the entity manager you can wrap the method in try{} finally{entityManager.close()}

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but what about this line? `entityManagerFactory.close();`   is it needed? or when should i put this?

Comment: In the general case when you have application running 24/7 you dont have to close it. If you have long periods of inactivity then yes you can close it.

Comment: Hei why this answer is no longer accepted ? Has something changed ?